# What is the workflow for hosting a Bokeh plot on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bokeh

I built a Bokeh app locally and now I'm trying to get it on the Internet. I'm actually testing, so for now, I only want to get my app to run within a blank page. I bought a domain for that and I will only the Bokeh plot running on it, as a first test.

I searched a bit and I don't quite understand the whole workflow in order to achieve that. I have created an EC2 instance and I installed the anaconda4 package on it.

But what now? I'm not even sure that I did the right thing; could someone explain to me what would be the steps from having an app.py locally that runs fine, to having the same app.py running on a server and available to the general Internet.

Thanks!